# I like to install CodeIgniter on my root How can I do it?

Tags: codeigniter-2

I am new to CodeIgniter, created a simple app on xampp in my local machine under localhost/ci, and it worked fine, but when i uploaded the files to my server's root (example.com) im only getting 404 from CI.

I like to go to my main controller when I visit example.com.
How can I do that.

Comment: Have you check your config.php? Owner of application/cache? Any message in the error_log? mod_rewrite .htaccess correct?

Comment: I am new to CI, can you tell me what I have to look for in those files

Answer (score 1):

Change the config file located in: .../applications/config/config.php.

Scroll down and you will find a section like this one:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/

$config['base_url'] = '';

....
```

Change the value assigned to `$config['base_url']` to be your  cloud server path.

for example:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.yoursite.com'
```

correct me if i wrong becouse i am a newbie too :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .htaccess make sure your RewriteBase is set correctly. I've had to set it to use "/" and sometimes "/user/var/www/" depending on the system/setup.

The best method for me testing if it's an .htaccess issue is to remove the .htaccess file and try using the index.php method to access my controllers. If I can access them from that point...I know the issue was a bad config error on my part.